# Unable to install maven in windows xp

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables, maven-3

I have installed Maven3.04 as described in the steps found at:

http://maven.apache.org/download.html

I'm running an XP machine. I created the user variable and added the bin
path to the path variable. However, when I try to run the mvn --version
command to verify it is installed correctly I get the following error:

```
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

However, if I use the command as follows I get the expected result:

```
C:\maven\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin>mvn --version

Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 14:14:56+0530)
Maven home: C:\maven\apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.6.0_11, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows xp", version: "5.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

Am i missing something out..???

Comment: So it's just a problem with the path. Have you tried restarting (the terminal or the OS)?

Comment: Ya i have tried that..same procedure i followed for windows 7 and its working their fine...below is my path variable:%M2_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, your PATH variable is not set. Try to set it to:

```
 PATH=%PATH%;C:\maven\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin
```

Comment: OOH yes  missed the obvious...thanks for pointing out...its working now..:-)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows and Linux you can only run programs which are in your PATH (unless you give the directory as well) On Windows, the current directory is implicitly in your path, On linux it is not.

Once you have added the maven bin directory to your path and restarted any windows which this needs to be added to you will be able to run `mvn`